# Postgresql c function returning one row with 2 fileds

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in postgresql c function and I start following examples.

I want to write a simple function that has inside an SQL and receiving parameter evaluete and return 2 fields as sum of 2 columns, separately (for now to be simpler).

The function below has problem passing the check

```
(get_call_result_type(fcinfo, &resultTypeId, &resultTupleDesc) != TYPEFUNC_COMPOSITE)
```

If I remove this line I get 1 integer as result  from this query

```
select * from pdc_imuanno(2012);
```

and error from

```
select (a).* from pdc_imuanno(2012) a;
```

because is not a composite type.

Question is I how I can prepare template for tuple if it's not correct this

```
resultTupleDesc = CreateTemplateTupleDesc(2, false);
TupleDescInitEntry(resultTupleDesc, (AttrNumber) 1, "abp1", FLOAT4OID, -1, 0);
TupleDescInitEntry(resultTupleDesc, (AttrNumber) 2, "abp2", FLOAT4OID, -1, 0);
```

And more in

```
get_call_result_type(fcinfo, &resultTypeId, &resultTupleDesc)
```

fcinfo what is and where come from?

source table:

```
CREATE TABLE imu.calcolo (
  codfis character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  anno integer NOT NULL,
  abp1 numeric,
  abp2 numeric,
  CONSTRAINT imucalcolo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codfis, anno)
)
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
-------------------------------------------------------
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"
#include "lib/stringinfo.h"
#include "miscadmin.h"

#include <math.h>

#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "utils/guc.h"
#include "utils/lsyscache.h"
#include "utils/memutils.h"
#include "utils/numeric.h"

#include "access/htup_details.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(test_query);
Datum test_query(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

Datum
test_query(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  TupleDesc resultTupleDesc, tupledesc;
  bool bisnull, cisnull;
  Oid resultTypeId;
  Datum retvals[2];
  bool retnulls[2];
  HeapTuple rettuple;

  sprintf(query,"SELECT anno, abp1::real, abp2::real "
                "FROM imu.calcolo WHERE anno = %d;",PG_GETARG_INT32(0));

  int ret;
  int proc;
  float abp1 = 0;
  float abp2 = 0;
  SPI_connect();
  ret = SPI_exec(query,0);
  proc = SPI_processed;

  if (ret > 0 && SPI_tuptable != NULL)
  {
    HeapTuple tuple;
    tupledesc = SPI_tuptable->tupdesc;
    SPITupleTable *tuptable = SPI_tuptable;
    for (j = 0; j < proc; j++)
    {
      tuple = tuptable->vals[j];
      abp1 += DatumGetFloat4(SPI_getbinval(tuple, tupledesc, 2, &bisnull));
      abp2 += DatumGetFloat4(SPI_getbinval(tuple, tupledesc, 3, &cisnull));
    }
  }
  resultTupleDesc = CreateTemplateTupleDesc(2, false);
  TupleDescInitEntry(resultTupleDesc, (AttrNumber) 1, "abp1", FLOAT4OID, -1, 0);
  TupleDescInitEntry(resultTupleDesc, (AttrNumber) 2, "abp2", FLOAT4OID, -1, 0);

  if (get_call_result_type(fcinfo, &resultTypeId, &resultTupleDesc) != TYPEFUNC_COMPOSITE) {
    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
                    errmsg("function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record")));
  }
  resultTupleDesc = BlessTupleDesc(resultTupleDesc);
  SPI_finish();
  retvals[0] = Float4GetDatum(abp1);
  retvals[1] = Float4GetDatum(abp2);
  retnulls[1] = bisnull;
  retnulls[2] = cisnull;
  rettuple = heap_form_tuple( resultTupleDesc, retvals, retnulls);
  PG_RETURN_DATUM( HeapTupleGetDatum( rettuple ) );

}
```

---

creation function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pdc_imuanno(integer)
RETURNS float
AS 'pdc','test_query'
LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;
ALTER FUNCTION pdc_imuanno(integer) OWNER TO www;
```

query:

```
select * from pdc_imuanno(2012);
```

Ok I find the simple and silly error
I create the function retunrning 1 field by myself and I expeted to see as return 2 fields.

with this creation sql it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION pdc_imuanno(integer)
RETURNS TABLE(abp1 real, abp2 real)
AS 'pdc','test_query'
LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;
```

Anyway it works with limited number of rows to sum and if I extend the rows number it crash
in this point

```
rettuple = heap_form_tuple( resultTupleDesc, retvals, retnulls);
```

I guess there are some error in types for values

so I query on the table fields as numeric::real, I get them as float4 and I output them as datum.

Where is my error?

Thanks a lot for any help.

This in my first post in StackOverflow.

Luca

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Please show the full compileable C file.

Comment: PostgreSQL I use is 9.3 on linux box.

Comment: Looks like you identified the problem as a function signature vs declaration mismatch. I'm glad. If you have follow-up questions please post new questions. Link back to this one for context. Include an explanation of what you are trying to do, not just your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in:
>
> `get_call_result_type(fcinfo, &resultTypeId, &resultTupleDesc)`
>
> `fcinfo` - what is and where come from?

`fcinfo` is part of `PG_FUNCTION_ARGS` in the v1 calling convention. It's the context of the function call and contains all sorts of details like parameters, etc. Much of this is handled behind the scenes by the `GETARG` macros, etc, but you need to pass it around to helper functions.

The rest of the question is hard to understand because of the typos etc. I'm *guessing* that you want to write a function in C to add two values together and return the result? If so, that doesn't make much sense to return as two fields in a composite type. Please show the relevant `CREATE TYPE` statements, the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` declaration you used to define the function, and explain what you are trying to do and why.

(If you edit your question, post a comment in reply to this answer otherwise or I won't know you edited.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig, I've improved question.